# if $x\le y+z$ for every $z>0$ then $x\le y$

Tags: real-numbers, alternative-proof

Here's what I have to show:

> If $x\le y+z$ for every $z>0$ then $x\le y$.

I tried proof by contradiction but it does not seem to work. Suppose $y<x$. Then $x-y>0$. Let $z_{0}=x-y$. Then $x\le y+z_{0} \Rightarrow x\le x$ which is true. Had $x$ been strictly less than $y+z$, it would have worked.

Can I get hints?

Comment: If $x-y>0$ then there is $0<1/n<x-y$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Q}$. To show this just take $n>1/(x-y)$. Then $x-y>1/n$ implies $x>y+1/n$.

Comment: Try $z_0 = \frac{x-y}{2}$.

Comment: Setting $z = x -y$ is a good idea but that gives you $x \le x$.  But what if $z < x-y$.  Then gives you $x \le y+z < x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Had x been strictly less than y+z, it would have worked."

So instead of making $z = x-y$ make $0 < z < x-y$.

Then $x \le y + z < y + x-y = x$.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.  Assume that $x\gt y$, then set $z=\frac{x-y}2\gt0$. That would mean that $x=y+2z\gt y+z$ and $z\gt0$, which is a contradiction.